# How to start MusicPlayer without specifying any music file in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player

In my app, I want to launch standard Music Player (with its full UI) when a button is pressed but I dont want to specify any file. I just want to open the player and then user can use it however they want. So the standard way of using intent with `ACTION_VIEW` and specifying media file will not work for me. So how can I launch this? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the intent explicitly to the Music Player activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourclass.class)
```

I think it should be `com.android.Music.MediaPlaybackActivity.class` but I'm not so sure about that part. If you want the browser, replace the activity with `MusicBrowserActivity`

Comment: Note that there's no insurance that this is the music player they have installed, if they have one at all.